# Pandas check time series continuity

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with monthly index. I want to examine whether the time index is continuous on the monthly frequency, and, if possible, spots where it becomes discontinuous e.g. has certain "gap months" between two months that are adjacent in its index.

Example: the following time series data

```
1964-07-31    100.00
1964-08-31     98.81
1964-09-30    101.21
1964-11-30    101.42
1964-12-31    101.45
1965-03-31     91.49
1965-04-30     90.33
1965-05-31     85.23
1965-06-30     86.10
1965-08-31     84.26
```

misses 1964/10, 1965/[1,2,7].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) by month for add missing datetimes, filter it to new `Series` and if necessary grouping by years with create list of months:

```
s = s.asfreq('m')
s1 = pd.Series(s[s.isnull()].index)
print (s1)
0   1964-10-31
1   1965-01-31
2   1965-02-28
3   1965-07-31
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]

out = s1.dt.month.groupby(s1.dt.year).apply(list)
print (out)
0
1964         [10]
1965    [1, 2, 7]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**Setup**:

```
s = pd.Series({pd.Timestamp('1964-07-31 00:00:00'): 100.0, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-08-31 00:00:00'): 98.81, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-09-30 00:00:00'): 101.21, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-11-30 00:00:00'): 101.42, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-12-31 00:00:00'): 101.45,
               pd.Timestamp('1965-03-31 00:00:00'): 91.49, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-04-30 00:00:00'): 90.33, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-05-31 00:00:00'): 85.23, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-06-30 00:00:00'): 86.1, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-08-31 00:00:00'): 84.26})

print (s)
1964-07-31    100.00
1964-08-31     98.81
1964-09-30    101.21
1964-11-30    101.42
1964-12-31    101.45
1965-03-31     91.49
1965-04-30     90.33
1965-05-31     85.23
1965-06-30     86.10
1965-08-31     84.26
dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

If datetimes are not always last day of months:

```
s = pd.Series({pd.Timestamp('1964-07-31 00:00:00'): 100.0, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-08-31 00:00:00'): 98.81, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-09-01 00:00:00'): 101.21, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-11-02 00:00:00'): 101.42, 
               pd.Timestamp('1964-12-05 00:00:00'): 101.45,
               pd.Timestamp('1965-03-31 00:00:00'): 91.49, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-04-30 00:00:00'): 90.33, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-05-31 00:00:00'): 85.23, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-06-30 00:00:00'): 86.1, 
               pd.Timestamp('1965-08-31 00:00:00'): 84.26})
print (s)
1964-07-31    100.00
1964-08-31     98.81
1964-09-01    101.21
1964-11-02    101.42
1964-12-05    101.45
1965-03-31     91.49
1965-04-30     90.33
1965-05-31     85.23
1965-06-30     86.10
1965-08-31     84.26
dtype: float64

#convert all months to first day
s.index = s.index.to_period('m').to_timestamp()
#MS is start month frequency
s = s.asfreq('MS')
s1 = pd.Series(s[s.isnull()].index)
print (s1)
0   1964-10-01
1   1965-01-01
2   1965-02-01
3   1965-07-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Ok, now I got it

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `.asfreq` relies on the dates being the last day of a month, which however isn't guaranteed in my problem. E.g., I may have dates that go like `2001/1/15`, `2001/2/1`, `2001/3/31`, `2001/5/14` and I still want to identify `2001/4` as missing. The point is I don't (and can't) care about the date but only care about the month. Does there exist an easy tweak of your code that  can make it work for this case?

Comment: @Vim - I have one idea, but rather first test it.

Comment: @jezrael, you will definitely crack it :-)

Comment: @Vim - Solution is convert it to first day of month and then use `MS` for month start frequency like `s.index = s.index.to_period('m').to_timestamp()` and then 
`s = s.asfreq('MS')`

Answer (score 7):

I often do that by calculating  the gap between each index value.

```
times_gaps = df.index - df.index.shift(1)
```

Then you can plot those:

```
times_gaps.plot()
```

If there are gaps, you will quicky see where.
If there are no gap, you will see a straight horizontale line.

You can also select gaps times doing:

```
times_gaps[times_gaps> threshold]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is perhaps not what I want. I'd like to see a programmatic approach so it doesn't have to rely on human inspection.

Comment: then you can select index time, when threshold > 32 days.
You will have a list of gasp times and the size of those gaps.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a dataframe as in your input (first columns are dates), you could do the following:

```
all = pd.Series(data=pd.date_range(start=df[0].min(), end=df[0].max(), freq='M'))
mask = all.isin(df[0].values)
print(all[~mask])
```

**Output**

```
3    1964-10-31
6    1965-01-31
7    1965-02-28
12   1965-07-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The idea is to create a date range with monthly frequency starting from the first date until the last date, and then check those values against your first column.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, because this is flexible as it does not rely on a index but can rather take any column.

Comment: If i wanted the frequency to weekly and daily what letter should be used?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample time-series data
dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=12, freq='M')
data = range(12)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'value': data})

# Check if the time-series is continuous for every month
df_monthly = df.set_index('date').resample('M').mean()
if df_monthly.isnull().sum().sum() == 0:
    print("The time-series is continuous for every hour.")
else:
    print("The time-series is NOT continuous for every hour.")
```